# Training a model with a series of text responses as input

Tags: classification, nlp, text-classification, sentiment-analysis

I want to train a binary classifier on text -- so something like sentiment analysis, but my input vectors are going to be a series of responses from some user separated by some separator character. I don't want to separate the responses per vector -- each vector must correspond to responses from a user. For example, an input vector could be like

```
['Hi there | i'm eating breakfast u? | okay talk to you later']
```

However, I've never dealt with inputs of this form when training a model. Has this kind of problem been tackled be for? How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the model/library you want to use. I will make you two examples here.

#### sklearn

In `sklearn` you can train your model by applying a transformation converting your text data into numbers (*e.g.* tfidf) and then using a classifier (*e.g.* random forest).

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# note data are a list of strings
data = ["Hi there", "i'm eating breakfast u?", "okay talk to you later"]
labels = [1, 0, 1]

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier()),
])

# train classifier
pipeline.fit(data, labels)

# evaluate all steps on new data
predicted = pipeline.predict('Hello predict this')
```

#### tensorflow

Analogously in tf, you have plenty of possibilities (even pass directly strings to the model and then use a conversion layer).
I strongly advise having a look at the documentation or at [tutorials available](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification).

Here I will show you one with an LSTM-based neural network classifier.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

max_len = 6 # all the sentence must have the same lenght
data = np.array(["Hi there", "i'm eating breakfast u?", "okay talk to you later"])
labels = np.array([1, 0, 1]])

tokeniser = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokeniser.fit_on_texts(data)

tokenised_text = tokeniser.texts_to_sequences(data)
tokenised_text = tf.keras.prepocessing.sequences.pad_sequences(tokenised_text, maxlen=max_len)
vocab_size = len(tokeniser.word_index) + 1

# This is a model I am inventing right now, you have to change it according to your problem
def build_model(emb_dim, dropout_rate, n_units, n_labels = len(labels)):
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(input_shape = (max_len,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, output_dim = emb_dim)(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(n_units)(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_labels, 'softmax')(x)
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = x)
    model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

then, you can fit your model on tokenised sequences

```py
model = build_model(emb_dim, dropout_rate, n_units)
model.fit(tokenised_text, labels, epochs = 10)
```

In tf you can really give several different kinds of inputs, but you have to build your model accordingly.

Comment: My input needs to be what might be called a concatenation of a few docs. For instance, instead of having your data be something like ["Hi there", "i'm eating breakfast u?", "okay talk to you later"], how would you train an input doc like "Hi there || i'm eating breakfast u? || okay talk to you later"?

Comment: So _one_ training example would be "Hi there || i'm eating breakfast u? || okay talk to you later"? If so, you can set a special token in the tokeniser (the "||") and train on a bunch of documents.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this "special token in the tokeniser"?

Comment: It is a token, corresponding to a series of characters with a "special meaning", like in your case the separation token "||". `tokenizer.add_special_tokens(["||"])`

Comment: Would this be able to preserve the idea that even though responses are separated by that special token, that they are connected in that they are all responses from the same user?

Comment: Yes, for the model _one_ sample is _one_ string given by the user replies concatenated and separated by "||".

Comment: That's great to know, thanks. Do you know which libraries support this `add_special_tokens` method? SpaCy maybe?